# React-router URL changes but page is still unchanged

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to react and react-router, so please go easy on me.

I am trying to implement router in my Todo List project, where path="/" takes me to my todo list and path="/id" takes me to a test page (later will show the description of the task).

When I click the link that takes me to "/id", the URL in the browser changes but the page/content doesn't. However, when I refresh my browser, the test page loads.

I have put the Switch in App.js shown below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Test from "./components/Test";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="todo-app">
          <p>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </p>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={TodoList} />
            <Route path={`/id`} component={Test} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

And I have put the Link to "/id" as shown below in a child component of component  which is called here in App.js.

```
<div key={todo.id}>
    <Link className="todo-text" to={`/id/${todo.id}`}>
      {todo.text}
    </Link>
</div>
```

Am I missing something which is causing my  component to not load when I click the link?

Edit: Here's a link to my project. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7cpjp9?file=src/index.js

Comment: Where are the links to the "/id" route being rendered, and how are they rendered? Can you share *that* component code? Shouldn't also the route path be something like `"/id/:id"` to match the computed URL/path linking to it?

Comment: @DrewReese
TIL we can do "/id/:id", I didn't know this was possible. I've changed that, but the problem is still the same. 
I have linked my project in the edit above, can you please check it out and help me what I might have done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Ok, the issue is exactly as I had suspected. You are rendering multiple routers in your app. The first is a `BrowserRouter` in your index.js file, the second, another `BrowserRouter` in App.js, and at least a third `BrowserRouter` in Todo.js. You need only one router to provide a routing context for the entire app.

The issue here is that the router in `Todo` component is the closest router context to the links to specific todo details. When a link in `Todo` is clicked, this closest router handles the navigation request and updates the URL in the address bar. The blocks, or "masks", the router in `App` component or index.js that is rendering the routes from "seeing" that a navigation action occurred. In other words, the URL in the address bar is updated by the inner router, but the outer router doesn't know to render a different route.

## Solution

Keep the `BrowserRouter` wrapping `App` in index.js and remove all other routers used in your app.

App - Remove the `Router` component. Also, reorder the routes/paths from most specific to least specific so you don't need to specify the `exact` prop on every route. Allows more specific paths to be matched and rendered before less specific paths by the `Switch` component.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="todo-app">
        <p>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </p>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/id/:todoId" component={Test} />
          <Route path="/" component={TodoList} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Todo - Remove the `Router` component. Move the `key={todo.id}` up to the outer-most element so when todos array is updated React can reconcile updates.

```
class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: null,
      value: "",
      details: "",
    };
    this.submitUpdate = this.submitUpdate.bind(this);
  }

  submitUpdate(value) {
    const { updateTodo } = this.props;
    updateTodo(this.state.id, value);
    this.setState({
      id: null,
      value: "",
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { todos, completeTodo, removeTodo } = this.props;
    if (this.state.id) {
      return <TodoForm edit={this.state} onSubmit={this.submitUpdate} />;
    }

    return todos.map((todo, index) => (
      <div
        className={todo.isComplete ? "todo-row complete" : "todo-row"}
        key={todo.id}
      >
        <div>
          <Link className="todo-text" to={`/id/${todo.id}`}>
            {todo.text}
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div className="icons">
          <RiCloseCircleLine
            onClick={() => removeTodo(todo.id)}
            className="delete-icon"
          />
          <TiEdit
            onClick={() => this.setState({ id: todo.id, value: todo.text })}
            className="edit-icon"
          />
          <RiCheckboxCircleLine
            onClick={() => completeTodo(todo.id)}
            className="delete-icon"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am learning router from youtube tutorials, so I did not realize that I am not supposed to use BrowserRouter multiple times, and I fixed my Routes. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all the approach, you are taking for dynamic routing is wrong.
It should be like this you will have to add the exact keyword on the dynamic route.

```
<Route exact path="/id/:todoId" component={Test} />
```

And

```
<div key={todo.id}>
<Link className="todo-text" to={`/id/${todo.id}`}>
  {todo.text}
</Link>
```

Comment: "/id" is a path prefix to "/id/:todoId", so the computed path would/should be matched and rendered. The match param is useful once rendered within the component. OP is saying that the component isn't being rendered though, so I don't suspect this is the issue nor the fix. Also, when using the `Switch` component if you order the routes correctly you ***almost never*** need to specify the `exact` prop on the `Route` components since the `Switch` exclusively matches.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import TodoList from "./components/TodoList";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Test from "./components/Test";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="todo-app">
          <p>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </p>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={TodoList} />
            **<Route exact path={`/id`} component={Test} />**
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```